# "infinite scroll" code working only for top scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, infinite-scroll

I'm using a "universal" piece of js that should detect if the user has scrolled to the bottom of the document:

```
 $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
            //ajax code here
        }
    });
```

As the user scrolls, new content should load via the ajax call.

I would have expected the code to fire when I scroll DOWN, but the condition is actually firing when I scroll back to the TOP of the page, so it's basically doing the opposite of what it's "supposed" to do.

I've seen this solution being used in many examples, such as:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17078097/1623095

My debugging messages:

```
console.log($(window).scrollTop());
console.log($(document).height());
console.log($(window).height());
```

These output when scrolling to the top:

```
0 
1956 
1956
```

And bottom:

```
961 
1956
1956
```

The only plugin being loaded in my page is jquery (1.10.0.min), due to the nature of the project, I cannot link to the page.

Thoroughly confused by the dom behavior here.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this some time before for someone else.

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20972183/2012636):

**Code**

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
        //- 10 = desired pixel distance from the bottom of the page while scrolling)
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 10) {
            var box = $("#scrollbox");
            //Just append some content here
            box.html(box.html() + "<br />fa");
        }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MdrJ4/3/)

Just place your ajax code where I extended the content with simple html breaks

Comment: Are you boored or something that you keep improving my post?
I dont think we need this duplicate answer here

Comment: The condition is being triggered when I scroll anywhere, not just the bottom of the page, which is not the desirable result at all.

Comment: No, its firing when you scroll down and was tested. You are doing something wrong. Ofcourse your scrolling element must have atleast as much height as current browser window or it will think it is already at the bottom so you should use min-height for your main content container.